# How to delay or postpone code execution in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, activex, delay, execution

**Scenario**

Create a blank workbook and add a ToggleButton and an InkPicture control (the latter inserted by means of ActiveX Controls -> More Controls). In the `SizeChanged` event of the InkPicture control, add the line:

```
Sheet1.ToggleButton1.Caption = "foo bar"
```

**Problem**

A "*Method or data member not found*" error in the line above that highlights the occurence of `.ToggleButton1` from that line.

**Reason**

The ink picture's `SizeChanged` event happens before the toggle button is created, and in some cases, the event occurs before the workbook's `Open` event! You can `Debug.Print` relevant messages in the Immediate Window to see that.

**Question**

How can I postpone the execution of the ink picture's `SizeChanged` code until the toggle button is created and can be accessed as a property of the worksheet? I can, of course, workaround the issue by creating a `Boolean` variable to avoid the InkPicture's `SizeChanged` event's execution until the end of the workbook's `Open` one, but this is only paper over the cracks and doesn't solve the actual issue.

**What I've tried**

- stopping the debugger, re-compiling the VBA project and saving it
  afterwards
- add `DoEvents` before the line above
- set the toggle button's `AutoLoad` property to `True`, in an attempt
  to create the toggle button *before* the ink picture

Every attempt appeared to work after saving and reopening the workbook, only to fail on subsequent saves and openings.

Note: I've edited my post to be more concise and easy to read, so try not to be overzealous and downvote a legitimate question...

Comment: Do you know exactly which line of code triggers your error?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in my post: the second to last line of code in the `SetFormArea()` sub (i.e. the one starting with `ControlMenuUserForm.Left`...). The error highlights the first occurence of `.ControlMenuToggleButton` from that line.

Comment: By the way, the error can easily be replicated by creating a blank workbook with just a (toggle, for consistency) button and an ink picture control, then adding a simple line like `Sheet1.ToggleButton1.Caption = "foo bar"` in the `SizeChanged` event of the ink pictrure control. I should have included this in the original post, as it's a much shorter explanation of what happens. I'm using the 2016 version of Excel, if that matters.

Comment: I was able to reproduce from your comment above. Thank you. I have suggested an answer - hopefully it can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I went the same route, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't throw any error. The error you're getting is because the `SizeChanged` event is executed before the workbook's `Open` event, as I mentioned in my post - I doubt it's caused by a 'security thing'. A better choice would be to check **if the property/object exists on the sheet** and only then run the actual code. This way I can avoid an error or error handling (which I can already do with `On Error Resume Next`, but only for a single line of code). If you edit your answer in that direction and it works, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: To be clear, it's critical that the code is executed at the start as well, it's just that I can easily run it in the workbook's `Open` event, if the boolean returned after checking the object's existence in the `SizeChanged` event is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which properties you need to access, you can try and grab a reference to your control via the `Worksheet.OLEObjects` collection.

Example:

```
Private Sub InkPicture1_Resize(Left As Long, Top As Long, Right As Long, Bottom As Long)
    Dim oleObj As OLEObject

    Set oleObj = Sheet1.OLEObjects("ToggleButton1")
    oleObj.Left = 1
    oleObj.Top = 1
    '...
End Sub
```

In this way, you are interacting with the control through the OLEObject Interface. As such, some of the control properties may not be available. Normally, you can interact with the control through its specific control interface (ie, the ToggleButton interface) by grabbing the OLEObject.Object property.

```
Private Sub InkPicture1_Resize(Left As Long, Top As Long, Right As Long, Bottom As Long)
    Dim tb As MSForms.ToggleButton

    Set tb = Sheet1.OLEObjects("ToggleButton1").Object

    tb.Caption = "foo"
End Sub
```

However, this seems to cause an error when the workbook is starting up. I believe it is a security thing. But, at least this error is a runtime that you can catch and handle, as oppose to the unhandlable *Method or data member not found* compiler error you are seeing right now.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, it helped...in that I don't get an error if I add `Dim tb As OLEObject   Set tb = Sheet1.OLEObjects("ToggleButton1")   On Error Resume Next   tb.Object.Caption = "foo"   Err.Clear` in both the workbook's `Open` and ink picture's `SizeChanged`. The problem is that, after (manually) changing the caption to something else, the caption is not always changed to "foo" when the workbook is opened again. And even if it did, on a subsequent save it will be unchanged yet again. It's inconsistent from execution to execution, just like a bug)...and I wouldn't be surprised to be one.

Comment: In the end I solved this the way I was trying to avoid, by simply creating a `Boolean` variable named `initdone` and only executing the InkPicture's `SizeChanged` event code if the variable was `True`. This meant that I wasn't able to run the code from that event when opening the file, so I ran it from the end of the workbook's `Open` event instead. It works perfectly now and although a proper/true solution doesn't seem to be available and my implementation is different from the posted answer, I'll mark it as accepted as a reward for your interest in the matter and otherwise good idea. Thanks!

Comment: I looked for some other solutions, but all dead ends. As you said, this may be an quirk with excel/vba that requires your original idea to solve. I appreciate the reward!

Comment: You're welcome. I tried to avoid this because it requires care on future code editing to keep the order of things as they are, while the solution I was looking for had the potential benefit of being "universal" (meaning I didn't have to worry when altering the code in other places). In the end though, it has its own advantages, plus it helped me to correct some other unrelated "bugs" in the code. So it's all good.